# Make a graph in python from an incidency matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have created this incidency matrix in python using the following code:

```
import networkx as nx

nodes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
edges = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 5], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4], [3, 5], [4, 6], [5, 6]]

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
G.add_edges_from(edges)

incidence_matrix = -nx.incidence_matrix(G, oriented=True) 
print(incidence_matrix.toarray())
```

which had returned me this output:

```
[[ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [-1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0. -1.  0. -1.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0. -1. -1.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0. -1.  0.  0.  0. -1.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. -1. -1.]]
```

I wanted to plot the graph of this matrix but unfortunatelly I have no Idea about how can I make it. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I'm not entirely sure what you mean - is this what you want (see image below)?
This is probably the easiest way to visulise a 2d array.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.pcolormesh(incidence_matrix.toarray()) #plot matrix
plt.colorbar(im, ax=ax) #add colorbar
plt.show()
```

[image]